# PhpMailer: loading a while and then ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, email, loading, phpmailer

I am dealing with something strange..
I am setting phpmailer and if I have an error I get the error normally

```
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
```

actually if everything is good, the page loads a while and then it stops loading, getting in chrome the error: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (Impossible to load the page because the server didn't load the data)

This is the content

```
<?php

$mail = new PHPMailer();

// set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 645;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication

$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "my password"; // SMTP password

$email = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$mail->From = $email;

$mail->AddAddress("to@example.com", "Name");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject of the mail";

$mail->Body = "content";
$mail->AltBody = "content";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

of course I have included this files:

```
require_once('../library/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('../library/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes - just load the autoloader, that loads the class for you so that's all you need.

You've set `Port = 645`; I suspect you meant 465.

For gmail you should follow [the example from the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps): use `Port = 587` and `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`.

Comment: You're probably running into some connectivity issue and will eventually get a timeout. Read [the troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: I have corrected all but now the page started loading and loading and loading => http://www.moderactif.com/mail.php

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: It will tell you what's wrong in your server logs. This is basic PHP debugging. Read the docs I pointed you at.

Comment: actually i don't get any error; by adding "$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;" nothing and any of the other "issues" is my case :(

Comment: Your link gives me a 500 error after a while. If your server is not logging the reason why, your PHP config is broken. Turn on error display in your ini file or with ini_set.

Comment: the issue is that the web host doens't allow to edit the php.ini file

Comment: I tried hosting the file mail.php on another web host and it worked.. so I think the problem is with the webhosting, but how to solve this?

Comment: You can set most ini settings without access to the PHP.ini using ini_set, as I said. Look at display_errors.

Comment: I did, but nothing was displayed => white page or loading and loading again

Comment: And with SMTPDebug=3?

Comment: it's added now => http://moderactif.com/mail.php  / but it is still loading and stopping

Comment: You need to take a bit of initiative, look at what it's doing, be logical. Cut back the script until it starts behaving, then add stuff back in, check values until you find what's wrong. SO is not a remote debugging service.

Comment: If I asked here, it's because I have tried thousand times and I have no more ideas.

Comment: Seriously. Start with `echo 'hello'` and build up from there. You might have tried a zillion things, but if you're not logical, it's a waste of your time. It sounds like your web host is a bit useless, which doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to Upload the PHPMailer to 6.5.
beacause the php 7.x it's diferent
look that the code change a little bit